# Single Sign on - Editing Identity providers Metadata file

Tags: single-sign-on

I configured Single sign-on for my sandbox and then tested with standard user. Login by a standards user is successful. But for a portal user failed.

I read that it is required to provide with Portal Id to Identity Provider when setting up with Identity Provider. I downloaded metadata certificate file and tried to edit to include attributes values for Portal Id and Organisation ID. When I create a Single Sign using the edited XML file I got this error

Error: File cannot be read. Please specify an XML file containing your SAML settings. If the error reoccurs, consider downloading the file again from your identity provider.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://kairangi--CraigDev.cs3.my.salesforce.com" validUntil="2026-06-14T03:01:33.892Z" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
         <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
               <Certificate >
            </ds:X509Data>
         </ds:KeyInfo>
      </md:KeyDescriptor>
      <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
      <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://kairangi--CraigDev.cs3.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpPost"/>
      <md:SingleSignOnService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://kairangi--CraigDev.cs3.my.salesforce.com/idp/endpoint/HttpRedirect"/>

 <saml:AttributeStatement>
 <saml:Attribute FriendlyName="Friendly Name" Name="federationId"
NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:unspecified">
<saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">saml_portal_user_federation_id
</saml:AttributeValue>
<saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">SomeOtherValue
</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>

<saml:Attribute Name="portal_id">
<saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">06030000001324d
</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
<saml:Attribute Name="organization_id">
<saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:anyType">00DQ000000EeEto
</saml:AttributeValue>
</saml:Attribute>
</saml:AttributeStatement>

   </md:IDPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" entityID="https://kairangi--CraigDev.cs3.my.salesforce.com" validUntil="2026-06-14T03:01:33.892Z" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
   <md:IDPSSODescriptor protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
      <md:KeyDescriptor use="signing">
         <ds:KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data>
               <ds:X509Certificate>

Comment: The edited XML file